# Limit MKLocalSearch to a region

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I am using MKLocalSearch to search for places and display the result on the map.
The problem is that sometimes if a restaurant exists in another state for example, it goes to the another state, i want to limit results to my region.
Here is my code

http://pastebin.com/89TxwR7X

```
        let searchRadius: CLLocationDistance = 10000
    let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate, searchRadius * 2.0, searchRadius * 2.0)

    map.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
    request.naturalLanguageQuery = getRandomPlace()
    request.region = map.region

    let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
    search.start { response, error in
        guard let response = response else {
            print("There was an error searching for: \(request.naturalLanguageQuery) error: \(error)")
            return
        }

        for item in response.mapItems {
            self.dropPinZoomIn(item.placemark)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot prevent the response from including results that are across some artificial boundary. You have defined a `region` for your request and the results will favor that region. But even then, the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit/mklocalsearchrequest/1451919-region) are quite clear:

> Specifying a region does not guarantee that the results will all be inside the region. It is merely a hint to the search engine.

So, what you get is what you get. You cannot prevent the server from returning the results that it returns.

If you *then* want to run through the returned `response` map items and *not* make placemarks for some of them because you don't like where they are, that is entirely up to you. But *your* code does *not* do that; you are just blindly making placemarks for *all* of them.

Answer (score -1):

easy solution

```
for item in res.mapItems {
            
            let n1 = item.placemark.coordinate.latitude - 0.2
            let n2 = item.placemark.coordinate.latitude + 0.2
            let n3 = item.placemark.coordinate.longitude - 0.2
            let n4 = item.placemark.coordinate.longitude + 0.2
            
            if n1...n2 ~= self.region2.center.latitude && n3...n4 ~= self.region2.center.longitude {
                print("Number is inside the range")
                self.locations.append(LandModel(placemark: item.placemark, distance: 0.0))
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).